# Display data, relational database with inertia + vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I need help, I am trying to display data with inertia and vue.js from a related database, but I get the following error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "categoria", subcategoria.categorias is undefined

Código

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Categoria;
use App\Models\SubCategoria;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class RelacionController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $subcategorias = SubCategoria::all();
        return Inertia::render('Subcategorias', ['subcategorias' => $subcategorias]);
        
    }
}
```

vista vue

```
<script>
import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        AppLayout,
    },
    props: ['subcategorias']
}
</script>

<tr v-for="subcategoria in subcategorias" :key="subcategoria.idSubCategoria">
  <td>{{ subcategoria.idSubCategoria }}</td>
  <td>{{ subcategoria.subcategoria }}</td>
  <td>{{ subcategoria.categorias.categoria }}</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to know how to get data from a relational database with Inertia and Vue.js, I know how to get data from a non-relational database, but I'm trying to show the products with their categories, but I can even though I already have everything related, I'm missing in the view.

Comment: Unless you believe there is a syntax error in that one line of code, and there's not, we do not have enough information to help you.  Your error says that categorias is undefined, why or how that is can only be determined if you provide more code and what debugging steps you've tried so far

Comment: I would like to know how to get data from a relational database with Inertia and Vue.js, I know how to get data from a non-relational database, but I'm trying to show the products with their categories, but I can even though I already have everything related, I'm missing in the view.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ¡Helpme please!